# How to map info from the relationship table from the many-to-many relatonship table into entity model class using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

How can I map information from the relationship table from a many-to-many relationship and map one or more of its properties to the entity from one of the table used in that query using AutoMapper.

For example, I have following 3 tables:

```
Part
====
PartId   Description
1        Part1
2        Part2
3        Part3

Object
======
ObjectId   Description
1          Obj1
2          Obj2

Objects_Parts
=============
ObjectId PartId  IsRequired
1        1       True
1        2     
2        1       True
2        3       True
```

My Part model object is defined as follows:

```
public class PartModel
{
    public int PartId {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public bool IsOptional {get;set;}
}
```

As you can see, I have the IsOptional property defined in the PartModel object and I want to map the IsOptional property from the relationship table to the relevant PartModel object.

I'm currently mapping this relationship as follow and it works fine but as mentioned, I need to map the IsOptional property from the relationship table to the relevant Part:

```
CreateMap<ObjectData, ObjectModel>()
    .ForMember(o => o.Parts, opt => opt.MapFrom(opt => opt.ObjectsParts.Select(o => o.Parts)));
```

How can I achieve this?

I hope the above makes sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have `PartData -> PartModel` mapping used by `Select` part of the `ObjectData.ObjectParts -> ObjectModel.Parts` mapping, remove the `Select` part and create the now required map `ObjectPartData -> PartModel`.

`ObjectPartData` contains all the data you need. Map the direct properties and use [IncludeMembers](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html#includemembers) to map the rest from the `PartData -> PartModel` mapping.

e.g.

```
// (1)
CreateMap<ObjectData, ObjectModel>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Parts, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ObjectParts)); // requires/uses (2)

// (2)
CreateMap<ObjectPartData, PartModel>()
    .IncludeMembers(src => src.Part) // requires/uses (3)
    .ForMember(dst => dst.IsOptional, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => !src.IsRequired));

// (3)
CreateMap<PartData, PartModel>();
```

Comment: I can see what you're doing but I'm still trying to figure out why it's not working. Does the code you provide only update the IsOptional field or does it map the entire part?

Comment: I ended up commenting all my mappings and starting from fresh into a single file as I had them broken down in different files which made it harder to figure. Once I did, and re-added each mapping one by one, and eventually got to your solution, it worked a charm! Thanks again!